# Php including pages with mod_rewrite hiding get variables issue

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I'm having trouble getting my mod_rewrite to work, so that links goes from`http://domain.com/page?home.php` to `http://domain.com/home`.

When entering `http://domain.com/` the home page is included correctly.

When entering `http://domain.com/404` or `http://domain.com/anythinghere` the 404 page is included correctly.

When entering `http://domain.com/home` a error 500 is raised and i get this error: `File does not exist: /var/www/html/domain/Dev/home`

Why does this not work?

My project is as follows:

Directory structure:

```
Dev/
    .htaccess
    index.php
    menu.php
    pages/
        404.php
        home.php
    resources/
        css/
            core.css
        fonts/
```

The .htaccess:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-f

RewriteRule ^(\d+)*$ ./index.php?page=$1
```

The index.php:

```
<?php

if ( !isset( $_GET['page'] ) )
    $_GET['page'] = 'home';

$pages = array('home');
$page  = $_GET['page'];

include( 'menu.php' );

if( in_array( $page, $pages ) )
{
    include( 'pages/' . $page . '.php' );
}
else
{
    include( 'pages/404.php' );
}

?>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The rewrite should be:

```
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)$ /index.php?page=$1 [L]
```

Comment: You are indeed correct thanks, although i put a point infront of /index.php... because im not working in the root folder, but same same.

RewriteRule ^([^/]+)$ ./index.php?page=$1 [L]